# Metal dynamically generate 2D texture at run-time?

Tags: ios, xcode, textures, arkit, metal

I'm working on a university project for which I want to texturize meshes which were generated using the new LiDAR sensor on recent Apple devices at run-time.

I've read some research papers about texturing 3D reconstructions and I want to try a 'simple' approach were mesh faces (triangles) are transformed to image-space of key-frames that were taken with the camera of the device. Then, I want to perform a pixel-lookup at the position of the triangle in the image and then add that part of the image to a texture map. When I keep track of all triangles in the mesh and determine its corresponding color in a relevant key-frame, I should be able to infer the texture / color of all triangles in the mesh.

Here is a demonstration of the aforementioned principle: [image: Lookup face color in image-space]

I need to do this natively in swift and therefore I will be using Metal for this. However, I have not worked with Metal before and my question is whether it is possible to "stich together" a texture from different image sources dynamically at run-time?